# Nuget - Where do I publish documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

When publishing a package through Nuget, specifically an SDK - What is the best practice regarding publishing the documentation (api reference for example)?
i.e - is there a specific place to upload documentation in the publishing process or should it be in Git only?

Comment: github pages ?????

Comment: You can use all approach such as setting up a web site similar to http://learn.microsoft.com . NuGet itself does not give you a way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For brief API reference, the common practice is [XML documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288481(v=vs.71).aspx) file[s] inside a NuGet package.

For full-fledged documentation, the best place is outside NuGet. Personally, for my SDK I upload CHM to release page on github. Technically, you can include everything you want in the package, but very few users will discover the documentation there, and for the majority of users it will just bloat the package size for no value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a xml file - [You can see here](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post1295_publish-your-net-library-as-a-nuget-package)

> Before you can create a NuGet package, you need something to package. At the very least you need a compiled assembly (.dll) for users to reference, but you should also include a documentation file (.xml). You’re allowed to create NuGet packages that don’t include a documentation file, but then users won’t see the many helpful method/class/parameter comments you’ve responsibly included in your code.